# MySQL Query to look up values in a second table

Tags: mysql

I'm a MySQL newby and for some reason this solution is eluding me.  I have two tables:

```
users
|--------------------------------------------------|
| user_id | user_name | email                      |
|--------------------------------------------------|
| 1       | user1     | user1@somedomain.com       |
| 2       | user2     | user2@someotherdomain.com  |
| 3       | user3     | user3@yetanotherdomain.com |
|--------------------------------------------------|

user_meta
|---------------------------------|
| user_id | meta_key | meta_value |
|---------------------------------|
| 1       | first_name | john     |
| 1       | last_name  | doe      |
| 2       | first_name | joe      |
| 2       | last_name  | schmoe   |
| 3       | first_name | harry    |
| 3       | last_name  | pickle   |
|---------------------------------|
```

I want a single query that produces this output:

```
|---------------------------------------------------------------|
| user_id | first_name | last_name | email                      |
|----------------------------------|----------------------------|
| 1       | john       | doe       | user1@somedomain.com       |
| 2       | joe        | schmoe    | user2@someotherdomain.com  |
| 3       | harry      | pickle    | user3@yetanotherdomain.com |
|----------------------------------|----------------------------|
```

I've tried several flavors of joins and tried subqueries but there must be some simple method that I'm missing.  I can get the first name or the last name but not both in the output.  Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Can you show us what you have tried?

Comment: Understanding how joins work in terms of data sets would help you.  Here's a [good article](https://blog.codinghorror.com/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins/)  which would show you how to join these tables and achieve the desired result.  Note: The key here is you have to join to user_meta twice from users (alias both joins)!  Once for 'first_name' and again for 'last_name'  Think that you have 3 sets of data.  An email address with a user_ID, a first_name data set with user_ID and a Last_name dataset with a user_ID.  show what you've tried, we can help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used left outer joins here because there is no guarantee that a first_name or last_name key will exist for a given user_id. In those instances, we will still show the user_id and email, but there will be NULL in place for the name.

```
SELECT U1.user_id, M1.first_name, M2.last_name, U1.email
FROM users U1
LEFT OUTER JOIN user_meta M1 ON M1.user_id = U1.user_id AND M1.meta_key = 'first_name'
LEFT OUTER JOIN user_meta M2 ON M2.user_id = U1.user_id AND M2.meta_key = 'last_name'
```

Comment: It was the double joins that threw me.  I didn't get that you have to treat the meta table as two separate tables.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

try this it would be helpful

```
select 
    u.user_id, 
    meta_value as first_name, 
    meta_value as last_name, 
    email
from users u left outer join user_meta um on u.user_id = um.user_id
group by u.user_id
```